# Is there something like an array of matrices?

Tags: c++

i was just thinking how can this be done... i mean this array could store several values in a very less no. of terms

for eg. an 3 term array of 3x3 matrix will have 27 terms grouped along with their matrices

Comment: There is if you build/use a Matrix struct or class...

Answer (score 4):

I guess you mean a tridimensional array, of course you can have them, eg

```
float ***values;
```

or

```
float values[10][5][5];
```

But I suggest you to stick with objects:

```
class Matrix {
  float **data;
}

vector<Matrix> matrices;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array of `int**`, with each `int**` pointing to its own set of `int[][]`s.